# react-native-vector-icon does not work properly

Tags: react-native, package, icons, frontend

I am using react-native icons from type ('mask'). However the icon does not show up when i run the app. 
[icon to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mNit.png)

Could anyone give an advice what the issue could be?

the code is:

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo'
<Icon name={'mask'} size={23} color={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'} 
          style={styles.usernameIcon}/>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code where you've used that `Icon`

Comment: link this lib worked for me

Comment: @SagarKulkarni, hi there. I did add the code but it has dissapeared,  i will re edit it now, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding the following code to the android/app/build.gradle

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf', 'AntDesign.ttf', 'Entypo.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf', 'Feather.ttf', 'FontAwesome.ttf', 'FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf', 'FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf', 'FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf', 'Foundation.ttf', 'Ionicons.ttf', 'MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf', 'SimpleLineIcons.ttf', 'Octicons.ttf', 'Zocial.ttf' ]
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Comment: Adding all of it poping the Error. How do we know each one's Extension. Is all of them are "ttf". Cause it's not working for me 

Comment: It worked when i removed all the FontAwesome Pro version